# Fetching array of objects from api and storing to usestate but getting empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to fetch data from the api ,storing it in redux store first and then trying to get it by useSlector and then storing it in local state ..when console.log i am getting the data but i am not able to store in in my local state.It is showing empty . I have included the image of console and my code.Please check

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oisCU.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJiNS.png)

Comment: Post code here as formatted code, not in images or via links. Also, there are plenty of answers here that deal with async data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (resultData) setLogs(resultData)
}, [resultData])
```

it will populate your state (`logs`) whenever `resultData` changes

Also you can just use your `resultData`(as well as `loadingdata`) straight in the component, for example, where you do `logs.map(log => ...)` just by `resultData.map(log => ...)` (don't forget to check it's not empty). 
And you can omit the `logs` and `loading` variables.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.It is wokring perfectly.Can u please explain what exactly we did here.I mean i tried to add this in the existing useeffect but it didnt work and started calling api indefinately.but when i tried in seperate useffects it is working perfectly.can u please tell why

Comment: @tanmay The `useEffect()` added has the dependency of `resultData`, so it is fired every time when `resultData` changes. And if it's not empty it sets your state.
And the existing `useEffect(()=> {},[])` with empty dependency array is working like `componentDidMount()`
You can learn more about hooks in the official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html